# PersistentLocalDateTimeAsString results in DateTimeParseException

Tags: spring, hibernate, java-8, mariadb

In the hibernate model when using jadira-usertype `org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentLocalDateTimeAsString` as Type, the conversion is not reversible.

```
@Column(name="requested_start")
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentLocalDateTimeAsString")
private LocalDateTime requestedStartDate;
```

When creating object with datetime in following format;

```
myObject.setRequestedStartDate(LocalDateTime.parse("2014-12-28T19:30:00"));
```

is stored in DB (MariaDB) as "2014-12-28T19:30" ignoring the seconds part (don't know why).

when querying back the data, I'm getting the following exception

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2014-12-28T19:30' could not be parsed at index 16
```

But, If I set date as "2014-12-28T19:30:01" with seconds set to "01", it is working fine.

I also tried setting the springframework's DateTimeFormat, still facing the same exception.

```
@Column(name="requested_start")
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentLocalDateTimeAsString")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime requestedStartDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this modified pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm[:ss]".

The meaning of the square brackets is indicating an optional part during parsing - see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).